# Looping in Python and keeping current line after sub routine

Tags: python

I've been trying to nut out an issue when looping in python 3.
When returning from sub routine the "line" variable has not incremented.

How do I get the script to return the latest readline from the 
subsroutine?

Code below

```
def getData(line):
      #print(line)
      #while line in sTSDP_data:
      while "/service/content/test" not in line:
            line = sTSDP_data.readline()

import os, sys

sFileTSDP = "d:/ess/redo/Test.log"
sTSDP_data = open(sFileTSDP, "r")

for line in sTSDP_data:
      if "MOBITV" in line:
            getData(line)   #call sub routine
            print(line)
```

I'm stepping through a large file and on a certain string I need to call
a sub routine to process the next 5 (or 100) lines of data. When the sub routine completes and returns to the main program, it would be better to have it continue on from the last 
readline in the sub routine, not the last readline in the main program.

Daan's answer did the trick.

Comment: This is a strange and convoluted script. Mind telling us what it is supposed to do?

Comment: If Daan's answer helped you, consider upvoting it (by clicking the up-arrow above the vote count on the left of the post) and marking it as the correct answer (by ticking the little checkmark under the votecount).

Answer (score 3):

How about using a return statement?

```
def getData(line):
      #print(line)
      #while line in sTSDP_data:
      while "/service/content/test" not in line:
            line = sTSDP_data.readline()
      return line

import os, sys

sFileTSDP = "d:/ess/redo/Test.log"
sTSDP_data = open(sFileTSDP, "r")

for line in sTSDP_data:
      if "MOBITV" in line:
            line = getData(line)   #call sub routine
            print(line)
```

Beware the scope of your variables. The 'line' in your getData function is not the same as the 'line' in your loop.

Answer (score 1):

Well, assignment does not work by reference. This means that if you reassign a variable in one function, then it won't modify values in another function (unless there are specific exceptions like `global` and `nonlocal`). (Please note: that is reassign, not modify. If you modify a list all references to the list are "modified").

Simply place `return line` at the end of getData(line)

```
def getData(line):
      #print(line)
      #while line in sTSDP_data:
      while "/service/content/test" not in line:
            line = sTSDP_data.readline()
      return line
```